# How we can create Wince 6.0 setup in windows 10?

Tags: windows-ce

Is it possible to create Wince Setup in Winodws 10? If yes ther how,
Actually I want to build Eboot source code and create image for that.
how can we build this source code in windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Generally to build Windows CE source code you need Platform Builder. 
This is a plugin for a specific version of Visual Studio.
CE6 - VS2005
CE7 - VS2008
CE2013 - VS2013/VS2015
If you plan to build for CE6 you'll have to install VS2005. I don't know if this is possible. For sure VS2008 works.
You can use a virtual machine running an older version of windows or, if you already have a WINCE600 folder backed up you can install VS2008 and Platform Builder and choose that folder as your CEROOT folder. This is not officially supported by MS (and will never be), but works for me and other people that needed to use old CE versions on a new PC.